# How can I merge two tables using ROWID in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge, oracle11g

I know that **ROWID** is distinct for each row in different tables.But,I am seeing somewhere that two tables are being merged using rowid.So,I also tried to see it,but I am getting the blank output.

I have person table which looks as:

[image]

**scrowid** is the column which contains rowid as:

```
alter table ot.person 
add scrowid VARCHAR2(200) PRIMARY KEY;
```

I populated this person table as:

```
insert into ot.person(id,name,age,scrowid) 
select id,name, age,a.rowid from ot.per a;
```

After this I also created another table **ot.temp_person** by same steps.Both table has same table structure and datatypes.So, i wanted to see them using inner join and I tried them as:

```
select * from ot.person p inner join ot.temp_person tp ON  p.scrowid=tp.scrowid
```

I got my output as empty table:

[image]

Is there is any possible way I can merge two tables using rowid? Or I have forgotten some steps?If there is any way to join these two tables using rowid then suggest me.

Comment: Two comments: (1) I can't reproduce this.  I take it you committed both transactions that inserted data? (2) Be aware that Oracle may move tables about, and if it does, rowids will change.  Storing rowids in tables is generally not a good idea.

Comment: ROWID is useful in some cases; joining tables on rowid isn't one of them, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are you using "merged" and "merging" (incorrectly!) to simply mean "joined" and "joining"? Or did you see `ROWID` used in a `MERGE` statement, and is that what's confusing you? In any case, the only way you could meaningfully join tables on `ROWID` is if you join a table **to itself**, not to a *different* table.

Comment: @Littlefoot - there are some cases when self-joining on `ROWID` can be useful (seen sometimes in `MERGE` statements, in `CONNECT BY` queries, etc.)

Comment: I stand corrected, @mathguy. Self joins **are** joins (though, not the ones I was thinking about). Thank you.

Comment: Storing ROWID's *anywhere* is an incredibly bad idea. If rows in your tables are ever moved so that their ROWIDs change (such as through a table move or a database restore) you have no way to recover the relation between the rows unless you have other columns in your tables which serve as **proper** foreign keys. I counsel against storing ROWIDs in the strongest terms.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica - that is a very important clarification of the OP's question. While he asks about using `ROWID` for "merging" tables (whatever that means), his attempt doesn't even do that - instead, it first **stores** `ROWID` values to use for <whatever>. That, as you stated, has absolutely no place anywhere.

Comment: *"I am seeing somewhere that two tables are being merged using rowid"* Where did you see this? And more pertinently, what exactly did you see? As you say, ROWID is "distinct for each row in different tables" so you need to explain what behaviour you're expecting, to join two tables by different keys.

Answer (score 1):

Define scrowid as datatype `ROWID` or `UROWID` then it may work.

However, in general the ROWID may change at any time unless you lock the record, so it would be a poor key to join your tables.

Comment: isnt it possbile if datatype is varchar2?

Comment: It should work due to implicit casting, however the second statement is more important.

Comment: The problem, obviously - regardless of data type - is that rowid's of rows in different tables will be different, so an inner join of different tables on rowid will be all but certain to be empty. Nothing to do with data type.

Comment: Also, about the ROWID possibly changing over time: that is not an issue for "joining on ROWID" (assuming that phrase would otherwise make sense). Why not? Because statements use ROWID (and all other values) *as they existed at a fixed point in time*. A SQL statement doing a self-join on `ROWID` will succeed, even if during the execution of the query some rows are moved around; the `ROWID` as they existed when execution started are the only values ever used in that execution of that query.

Comment: @mathguy, yes a self join is no problem. However, according to the question the ROWID's are stored in table and afterwards used for joining. This may fail.

Comment: Right - while the OP asked about using `ROWID` for joins, in fact what he describes is different - he is using stored values of `ROWID`, rather than actual `ROWID`. That is indeed a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you misunderstood the merging of two tables via rowid, unless what you actually saw was a Union, Cross Join, or Full Outer Join. Any attempt to match rowid, requardless of you define it, doomed to fail. This results from it being an internal definition. Rowid in not just a data type it is an [internal structure](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns008.htm#SQLRF00254) (That is an older version of description but Oracle doesn't link documentation versions.) Those fields are basically:
 - The data object number of the object
 - The data block in the datafile in which the row resides
 - The position of the row in the data block (first row is 0) 
 - The datafile in which the row resides (first file is 1). The file
   number is relative to the tablespace.

So while it's possible for different tables to have the same rowid, it would be exteremly unlikely. Thus making an inner join on them always return null.

Comment: I updated the reference to now point to version 12c. Part of that says "Usually, a rowid value uniquely identifies a row in the database. However, rows in different tables that are stored together in the same cluster can have the same rowid". A further link to  [Rowid Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50998) clarifies "The data object number, which is an identification number assigned to every database segment. ... Objects that share the same segment (clustered tables in the same cluster, for example) have the same object number".

Comment: is this available in oracle 12c? I am using oracle 11g

Comment: Hard to believe, because ROWID holds the position of the row in the data block. Thus I would have assumed even when tables share the same object number and the same data block then position of the row in the data block makes it still distinct.

Comment: One would think! just quoting/linking to Oracle Documentation. @Random guy, this would be available for v11, but Oracle does not seem consistent with the names, so don't know the exact link.. However, an earlier version referenced v10 and that is identical with v12. I would guess V11 would be the same.